# Autocorrelation and PSD

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, homework, random-process

Let $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ be two orthogonal processes with power spectral densities 
$$S_{xx}(f) = S_{yy}(f)=\begin{cases}
1-\lvert f\rvert, & \lvert f\rvert<1
\\[1ex]
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Define a new process $Z(t) = Y(t)-X(t-1)$. Determine and sketch the power spectral density $S_{zz}(f)$.

The solution is the following:
The autocorrelation function of the process is 
$$R_{zz}= E \bigg\{\big[Y(t-\tau)-X(t+\tau-1)\big]\big[Y(t)-X(t-1)\big] \bigg\} $$ 
And now comes the part which I do not understand at all. 
\begin{align}
R_{zz}&=R_{yy}(\tau)-R_{yx}(\tau+1)-R_{xy}(\tau-1)+R_{xx}(\tau)\\
&=R_{yy}(\tau) + R_{xx}(\tau)\ \quad\text{since}\quad R_{yx} = R_{xy} = 0 \quad\text{from orthogonality.}
\end{align}

Therefore, $S_{zz}(f)=2S_{yy}(f)=2S_{xx}(f)$ as shown below.
[image]

Can anyone explain it like I am five?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Expand the terms inside the expectation $E\{\ldots\}$, and then use the fact that the expectation of a sum equals the sum of the individual expectations (due to linearity).

Comment: So $Y(t+\tau)Y(t)-Y(t+\tau)X(t-1)-X(t+\tau-1)Y(t)+X(t+\tau-1)X(t-1)$ and then i can see in my notes that $R_{xx}(\tau) = E[X(t+\tau)X(t)]$ so it gives me the first line i dont understand. But how is $Ryx=Rxy=0$?

Comment: @Xraycat922: As you said in your question: "from orthogonality".

Comment: ah. Okay, last question why is the peak amplitude 2? (why $2 S_{yy}(f)$)

Comment: @Xraycat922: You get $S_{zz}=S_{xx}+S_{yy}$, and since $S_{xx}=S_{yy}$ you have $S_{zz}=2S_{xx}=2S_{yy}$. That was easy, wasn't it?

Comment: Hi Matt: I think the confusion ( atleast for me. maybe not the OP ) was that the relations between the correlations then can be used in the relations for the respective spectral densities. I imagine this is true because, for any stochastic process,  the spectral density at $\omega$ is t the moment generating function of the autocorrelations evaluated at $\omega$. I should say that I think this is the reason but I'm not positive. thanks for clarification.

Comment: @markleeds: I'm not sure where the confusion lies. I hope the OP leaves a comment if anything remains unclear. The PSD is simply the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation.